# Prevent resource from being retrieved - laravel observer

Tags: laravel

How can I prevent a resource from being shown up using laravel observers ?
I tried

```
class PostObserver
{
  public function retrieved(Post $post){
        if($post->id==1)
        return false;
  }
}
```

but didnt work .

**UPDATE**

I am building an API , so the Idea of an extra attribute of "shown or hidden" may not be efficient .

Comment: I would make a visible column and check that when loading or displaying posts. (So not using observers.)

Comment: ok , I didnt actually mention that I m building an API .. , so I think a blocked resource shouldnt appear in the response in anyway , it can be shown up easily ..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes)?

#### Example: Create a Scope `HiddenScope`

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class HiddenScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('is_hidden', !=, true);
    }
}
```

In your model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new HiddenScope);
    }
}
```

If you want to use a `is_hidden` that needs to be added to db, otherwise you could use `id != 1` like in your example. Then, you should be able to do `Post::all()` and not get the hidden models.

Comment: actually showing or hiding a post is not generalized to all users , if a user is blocked by another , he cant see his posts , so they must not be appearing in the response .. that's the idea .